# Write continuously to output file using Python lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I'm writing big chunks of data from a database down to an XML file. I'm using Python and its lxml library to create the file.
I notice that it's generating the whole XML file in memory and then outputs it to the file at the end, is there's a way to dump the xml file for every X number of database objects?

```
import lxml.etree as etree
import os

root = etree.Element('root')
db_obj1 = etree.SubElement(root, 'item')
db_obj2 = etree.SubElement(root, 'item')
db_obj3 = etree.SubElement(root, 'item')
et = etree.ElementTree(root)
et.write(sys.stdout)
```

I've tried with ElemenTree().write(), but can't find any setting or best-practice on how to accomplish this in the documentation at http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html.

Looking to decrease the total memory footprint.

Comment: Why would you want to dump a database to XML at all?  You might consider writing to a more natural rectangular format like CSV or HDF5 or something else which would avoid this issue completely, as well as provide a more space-efficient and regular format for your data on disk.

Comment: Integration with a legacy system @JohnZwinck, can't change this.

Answer (score 5):

From [the lxml docs](http://lxml.de/api.html#incremental-xml-generation):

> It is a common pattern to have one or more nested element() blocks,
>   and then build in-memory XML subtrees in a loop (using the ElementTree
>   API, the builder API, XSLT, or whatever) to write them out into the
>   XML file one after the other. That way, they can be removed from
>   memory right after their construction, which CAN LARGELY REDUCE THE
>   MEMORY FOOTPRINT of an application, while keeping the overall XML
>   generation easy, safe and correct. [Emphasis mine].

```
filename = "/tmp/somefile.xml"
with ET.xmlfile(filename, encoding='utf-8') as xf:
    xf.write_declaration(standalone=True)
    xf.write_doctype('<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "some.dtd">')
    with xf.element('root'):
        for value in '123':
            # construct a really complex XML tree
            el = ET.Element('item', attr=value)
            xf.write(el)
            # no longer needed, discard it right away!
            el = None
```

writes

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM "some.dtd">
<root><item attr="1"/><item attr="2"/><item attr="3"/></root>
```

to the file.